# Remove a single Object from any[] collection of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object declared like this in typescript

```
public profileDataSource: { Value: string, Key: number }[];
```

So I would have an object that looks like this

```
   0: Object {Value: "<Select Profile>", Key: null}
    Key:null
    Value:"<Select Profile>"
   1: Object {Value: "Profile 1", Key: 1}
    Key:1
    Value:"Profile 1"
```

How do I remove the object containing the value of "Select Profile"?

`profileDataSource.splice(0,1)` gives me an error that splice is not a function

Comment: It is an array. OP did not post the entire issue here so the question is unclear.

Comment: @briosheje yeah sorry, missed the `[ ]`. The undefined .splice just told me instantly it was about it's not an Array

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT oh, okay. Missed it as well when I first looked at it. Anyway, it's still unclear, it "should" work as expected, OP should provide an example to replicate the issue.

Comment: You could also just use "shift".  If it is the first item in the array, `shift()` will essentially pop off the front of the array.     unshift and shift are the same as push and pop for an array, but opposite ends of the datastructure.

Comment: Normally when doing things like this in angular, I would do something like: `<select><option [value]="base.value">{{base.string}}</option><option *ngFor="let item in list" value="item.value">{{item.string}}</option></select>`
Therefore the Default case is never in the data array.

Comment: splice not give me error [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20profileDataSource%3A%20%7B%20Value%3A%20string%2C%20Key%3A%20number%20%7D%20%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20Value%3A%20%22fds%22%2C%20Key%3A%201%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20Value%3A%20%22fds1%22%2C%20Key%3A%202%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20Value%3A%20%22fds2%22%2C%20Key%3A%203%20%7D%5D%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(profileDataSource)%3B%0D%0AprofileDataSource%20%3D%20%5B...profileDataSource.splice(0%2C%201)%5D%3B)

Comment: Probably your array still undefined, but there's no much code to be sure about that. Try to initialize your array: `public profileDataSource: { Value: string, Key: number }[] = []`

Comment: @Fallenreaper yea i went more with this approach

Comment: @TerranceJackson If I solved your question, please let me know, and I can work towards writing an answer for you.

Comment: @Fallenreaper yes it worked for me better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looked like to me you were using Angular. Mostly from the concept that you looked like you were working with some sort of dropdown.

I wanted to go over a solution in which solves problems like these.

Conceptually you want to create a dropdown, and each dropdown has a base case and its options.  The base case can be some sort of string to say select an option, or something else.  You can use this base case a way to validate as well for required states.

What I would do is something like follows.

Markup:

```
<select name="selection" [(value)}="selectionOption">
    <option [value]="base.value">{{base.label}}</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item in listOfOptions"
            [value]="item.value">{{item.label}}</option>
</select>
```

And then in your markup you could have something akin to:

```
class MyController {
    selectionOption: any;
    base : Item = { value: null, label: "<Select A Profile>" };
    listOfOptions: Item[] = [];

    ngOnInit() {
        //this.listOfOptions = ...; ///Whatever you want it to contain.
    }
   // Depending how you handle the data, with an NgModel, or FormGroup, you can validate that information.  If value is null, then no selection was done.  Otherwise, you can move to the next step in the validation pipeline.
}

class Item {
    value: any;
    label: string;
}
```